# Get Visio shape data from an embeded Excel object

Tags: excel, visio, ole

I have an embedded Excel-Sheet in Visio that represents the content of an array. Filling this sheet works fine.
What I want to do is, on one hand get shape info of the visio doc in my Excel sheet and update the shapes properties (shapesheet User-defined Cells) based on what has been filled on the excel sheet.

I know how to access Visio objects from visio, but I can't manage to access to the "parent" Visio document from the embeded Excel object.

In other words, to access a shape properties from Visio (I have a user-defined cell called "User.Type") :

```
Dim myType As String    
myType = ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes.ItemFromID(52).Cells("User.Type.Value").FormulaU
```

But how can I acces to the visio document from the embeded Excel object ?
It's probably very simple but I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks for your kind help

Comment: I would say this is not possible (there is no API to do that), but I am afraid this would not be an useful answer.

Comment: At least it woud stop wasting my time to find a solution, so thank you for that ;-)
But still, it would really be too bad not being able to get Visio information from an embeded Excel file. Can't understand why this feature does not exists....  :-(

Comment: I think embedding Excel sheet may be a bad idea, if you want to interact with data. Visio has a special feature for connecting shapes to Excel data, this is how it's supposed to work. Check out this one for example (something that came up in google first): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FDq596M7KA

Comment: Looks very interstinf indeed but... Requires Visio Pro whitch I don't have.... 
Thank you very much for your help, I now have to convince my boss to go for Visio Pro...